# Delete git repository from server from local command line

Tags: git

I have a git repo cloned locally. I want to permanently delete the repo from the server so other developers cannot check it out. This is to prevent confusion. How do I do this from my local command line?

Comment: Maybe this? https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-remote/

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì That remove the remote from the local repository.

Comment: you can delete all files(that are not in `.gitignore`) from the repo but not the entire repo

Comment: You want a git command to delete somebody else's repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done with git commands. However the [Github Developer API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository) allows you to delete from a shell, a repo hosted on github.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to physically remove a repo from a server I think you have to log into the server and remove the repo directory. If you are talking about github or something like that, they offer ways to remove repos.